# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, objective-c-blocks

I am using following code for downloading many images and update imageView in main thread after it get's downloaded.

Code for downloading one image (This is code executed for every image download):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //download image. Code to download image
    UIImage * tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myUrl]]];

    //if image downloaded
    if (tempImage)
    {
        // Run code to set image to UIImageView in main thread.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            myImageView.image = tempImage;
            [myImageView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    }
});
```

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS with code=1 on `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.
I think `tempImage` is autoReleased and may be released before calling to main thread but I am not sure that this is the issue for this particular crash.

I am using Xcode 6.1(so maybe not Xcode issue) and it is crashing on iOS 8.1

Log for Thread 98(Crashed at Thread 98)

```
#0 objc_retain ()
#1 __84-[MyController getTableCell:withCell:withIndexPath:]_block_invoke
#2 _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#3 _dispatch_client_callout ()
#4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#6 _pthread_wqthread ()
#7 start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (Thread 1)Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0 _dispatch_async_f_slow ()
#1 -[My_Controller getTableCell:withCell:withIndexPath:]
#2 -[My_Controller tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
#3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] ()
#4 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] ()
#5 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] ()
#6 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] ()
#7 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] ()
```

Main thread:

```
#0 __mmap ()
#1 mmap ()
#2 ImageIO_Malloc ()
#3 copyImageBlockSetPNG ()
#4 ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback ()
#5 CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int) ()
#6 CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) ()
#7 CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) ()
#8 CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) ()
#9 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#10 CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#11 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#12 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#14 __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 GSEventRunModal ()
#17 UIApplicationMain ()
#18  main
```

Comment: I got no exception running your code.

Comment: This crash is rare. only happens sometimes, can't figure it why. Added logs at the time of EXC_BAD_ACCESS if that might help. Also I am calling multiple instances of above given code.

Comment: Have you checked the code around `[MyController getTableCell:withCell:withIndexPath:]` because that's mentioned a lot.

Comment: Given code above is inside that method.

Comment: can you show the complete `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I am calling `[MyController getTableCell:withCell:withIndexPath:]` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Inside `getTableCell:withCell:withIndexPath` method I am initializing labels of table cell and having code mentioned above download image.

Comment: Have you tried running the app with zombie objects enabled? It looks like an object is being overreleased - NSZombie will confirm if it's the image object

Comment: @RichTolley Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the crash. By the way anything wrong in the code or I can improve.